# How to Pass our own Parameter from Html.BeginForm

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to pass some additional Parameter from My MVC Form to Controller. Can someone guide me how to achieve this. Now I want to Pass one more parameter Like

*StateName* and *CityName* with value from Form so that I can retrieve in my controller to save this. Can someone Guide me how to achieve this? My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "EmployeeRegistration", new }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Register Emp Information" style="text-align:center">
}
```

Thanks everyone I am able to pass but **my problem is I am getting some value from jquery which I want to pass from From sharing more code** to understand what is my problem

I have a dependent `DropDownList` Named *State* and *City*

```
@Html.DropDownList(m=>m.stateDDL, new SelectList(@ViewBag.stateDDL), "Select a State", new { id = "stateID" })
```

Now `onchange` event of this `DropDownList` I am getting the selected value with this code

```
$("#stateID").change(function () {
    var state = $('#stateID :selected').text();
    alert(state);
});
```

**Now I want to pass this selected Name from Form to controller**, Can someone tell me how to pass this state value

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(EmployeeRegistration empRegmodel,FormCollection form)
{
    var state = form["stateDdl"].ToString();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Er.registerEmpInfo(empRegmodel);
        return RedirectToAction("HomeScreen", "HomeScreen");
    }
    Er.getCountry();
    Er.getCity();
    Er.getState();
    ViewBag.countryddl = Er.country;
    ViewBag.cityddl = Er.city;
    ViewBag.stateddl = Er.state;
    return View("EmployeeRegistration");
}
```

Comment: Please show your controller code. You would normally have an Edit (or in this case Register) action method in your controller that takes a `HttpPost`'ed C# object with the named properties you desire, or in MVC 5 you can simply add named parameters (StateName, CityName) to the action.

Comment: @Rahul If your select is inside form you should be able to get selectedValue in stateDDL field of model

Answer (score 1):

Store the values in `Hidden`  fields and retrieve it at controller using `FormCollection`

**Update**  no need of jquery here

instead try this : add name attribute

```
 @Html.DropDownList(m=>m.stateDDL, new SelectList(@ViewBag.stateDDL), "Select a State", new { id = "stateID",name="stateID" })
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
   {
       var stateid=form["stateID"].ToString();
   }
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh thanks for updating by I am doing with an alternative way because I am facing issue with my dependent dropdownlist If I am chaging the dropdownlist value and second is populating based on first so second dropdownllist value is not saving it is coming as null do u have any idea how to resolve this

Comment: @Rahul how you save data in controller..have you added `name` attribute

Comment: you should use  `var temp = form["YOUR_ANOTHER_DROPDOWN_Name"].ToString();` to get another dropdown value..make sure you enter same name as you entered in view

Comment: I tried but I am not getting the values.I am facing this issue because of binding dropdownlist